# Fix the position of image in html

Tags: css

I have created an html document. Inside this I've imported an image under a paragraph. But whenever I change the resize my browser. The image disappears by moving below the page.

The image is given inside a card.

```
.Card{
  border:none;
  font-family: 'NCS Radhiumz';
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #000000;
  width:90%;
  height: 85%;
  margin-left: 80px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
```

I just want everything on the page to resize without disappearing from the page. I'm very new to coding.
Anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're most likely missing is some styling on your image element. Try this in your css file:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

You can experiment with different ways to fit the image in your component. Check out [these docs](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) for some options.

Answer (score -1):

you're asking for responsive web design. You can achieve that by implementing CSS Media Query.

Learning source:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Does this help my browser to automatically adjust the page upon resize?

Comment: yes, this will helps you to apply certain css in certain browser size